# filename how to stop and make paragraph into one string

Tags: python-3.x, filenames

so lets say i have a text file that looks like

> Limerick
>
> 8 A
>
> 8 A
>
> 5 B
>
> 5 B
>
> 8 A
>
> Quintain (English)
>
> 0 A
>
> 0 B
>
> 0 A
>
> 0 B
>
> 0 B

so far i just did my code

```
def parargraph(poetry_file):
    """(file open for reading) -> poetry pattern
    Return poetry pattern
    >>>paragraph('poetry_forms'.txt)
    ['Limerick',8,'A',8,'A',5,'B',5, 'B', 8, 'A'] 
    # same idea for quintain i'm trying to get it to loop and do same process like limerick
    """

    poetryfile = open('poetry_forms'.txt)
    line = poetry_file.readline()
    while line != '':
```

i'm still fairly new to coding so if you could stick with similar built-in functions i used in my code that would be appreciate

my main question is how would i to get python to read by paragraph so how to get the first loop to read from limerick until 8 A and stop so i can change it into a string then let it go through the loop again but for quintain

Answer (score 0):

So you want separate your file by empty lines?

Sample:

```
def paragraph(pFile):
with open(pFile + ".txt", 'r') as f:
    allPara = []
    simplePara = ''
    for line in f:
        if line != '\n':
            simplePara += line
            # simplePara.append(line)
        else:
            allPara += [ simplePara ]
            # allPara.append(simplePara)
            simplePara = ''
    return allPara

poetry = paragraph("poetries")
print(poetry) # This will be a list of paragraphs
# and you can print it:
for parag in poetry:
    print(parag)
```

The poetry will be a list - and each item of the list is one paragraph(including the new lines):

```
['Limerick\nWas\n8 A\n', '8 A\n', '5 B\n', '5 B\n', '8 A\n', 'Quintain (English)\n', '0 A\n', '0 B\n', '0 A\n', '0 B\n']
```